# Setting event listener on a specific layer (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, listener

Currently what I have is a zoom_changed listener that loads a layer when the zoom level is > 19. Once this layer has loaded it will be overlayed with other layers simultaneously.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){

        var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
        var map_id = 'idhere';

        if(zoomlevel >= 19){

            var lyr_reids = new google.maps.visualization.MapDataLayer({
                mapId: map_id,
                layerId: 'layerhere'
            });

            lyr_reids.setMap(map);
        }
    });
```

Now when this layer has loaded with the other layers, I want to set a click listener on this layer only. How do I specificy that I only want to listen for clicks on the lyr_reids layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it. In case you are interested:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){

    var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
    var map_id = 'idhere';

    if(zoomlevel >= 19){

        var lyr_reids = new google.maps.visualization.MapDataLayer({
            mapId: map_id,
            layerId: 'layerhere'
        });

        lyr_reids.setMap(map);
        reIdListener(lyr_reids);
    }
});



 function reIdListener(map){

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){

        //functions here
    })
    }
```